# How to load Photoshop png with LIBPNG?

Tags: loading, libpng

I am facing some problems to load some specific png images. Here are some helpful images.

1. Image #1 www.silexars.com/image.png (Doesn't load properly)
2. Image #2 www.silexars.com/image2.png (Loads fine)
3. Screenshot of Image #1 rendered with OpenGL
   http://www.silexars.com/screenshot.jpg
4. Screenshot of PNG Analyzer with both images open:
   http://www.silexars.com/screenshot.png Image #1 @ Left, Image #2 @
   Right

I've noticed that the left image has a chunk called cHRM and I believe I have to convert it somehow.
Would someone help me with this issue?

The code that I am using for loading the png file is:

```
uint8 Graphics::Image::loadPNG(FILE *fp) {
uint8 header[8];
fread(header,sizeof(header),1,fp);
if (png_sig_cmp(header,0,sizeof(header))) return INVALID_FILE;
png_structp png;
png_infop info;

png = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING,0,0,0);
if (!png) return FAILURE;
info = png_create_info_struct(png);
if (!info) {
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png,0,0);
    return FAILURE;
}

png_init_io(png,fp);\
png_set_sig_bytes(png,sizeof(header));

png_read_info(png,info);

delete[] data;
data = 0;

int32 bitdepth,colortype;
png_get_IHDR(png,info,&width,&height,&bitdepth,&colortype,0,0,0);

if (colortype == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE) {
    png_set_palette_to_rgb(png);
}
if (colortype == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY && bitdepth < 8) {
    png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8(png);
}
if (colortype == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY || colortype == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY_ALPHA) {
    png_set_gray_to_rgb(png);
}
if (png_get_valid(png, info, PNG_INFO_tRNS)) {
    png_set_tRNS_to_alpha(png);
}
if (colortype == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB) {
    png_set_filler(png, 0xff, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);
}
if (bitdepth == 16) {
    png_set_strip_16(png);
}
if (bitdepth < 8)
    png_set_packing(png);

png_read_update_info(png,info);
png_get_IHDR(png,info,&width,&height,0,0,0,0,0);

int32 rowbytes = png_get_rowbytes(png,info);

std::cout << rowbytes/bpp << std::endl;

data = new uint8[rowbytes*height];
png_bytep *row_pointers = new png_bytep[height*sizeof(png_bytep)];
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    row_pointers[height-1-i] = data + i * rowbytes;

png_read_image(png, row_pointers);

png_read_end(png,0);

delete[] row_pointers;
png_destroy_read_struct(&png,&info,0);
return OK;
}
```

Hope the info is enough. But if you need any extra data, just ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cHRM chunk in the first image is inconsistent with the color profile contained in the iCCP chunk.  It's best to just ignore the cHRM chunk.  But your code is already ignoring both the cHRM and iCCP chunks.  You can use the png_set_keep_unknown_chunks() to completely ignore them, in case one of them is causing the trouble you are seeing (libpng processes them even if your code ignores them, unless you use png_set_keep_unknown_chunks() to tell libpng that they should be never handled).

e.g., since you are ignoring all ancillary chunks in your application, tell libpng not to even process them:

```
`
    #ifdef PNG_HANDLE_AS_UNKNOWN_SUPPORTED
    /* prepare the reader to ignore all recognized chunks whose data won't be
     * used, i.e., all chunks recognized by libpng except for IHDR, PLTE, IDAT,
     * IEND, tRNS, bKGD, gAMA, and sRGB (small performance improvement) */
    {
        /* These byte strings were copied from png.h.  If a future libpng
         * version recognizes more chunks, add them to this list.  If a
         * future version of readpng2.c recognizes more chunks, delete them
         * from this list. */
        static /* const */ png_byte chunks_to_ignore[] = {
             99,  72,  82,  77, '\0',  /* cHRM */
            104,  73,  83,  84, '\0',  /* hIST */
            105,  67,  67,  80, '\0',  /* iCCP */
            105,  84,  88, 116, '\0',  /* iTXt */
            111,  70,  70, 115, '\0',  /* oFFs */
            112,  67,  65,  76, '\0',  /* pCAL */
            112,  72,  89, 115, '\0',  /* pHYs */
            115,  66,  73,  84, '\0',  /* sBIT */
            115,  67,  65,  76, '\0',  /* sCAL */
            115,  80,  76,  84, '\0',  /* sPLT */
            115,  84,  69,  82, '\0',  /* sTER */
            116,  69,  88, 116, '\0',  /* tEXt */
            116,  73,  77,  69, '\0',  /* tIME */
            122,  84,  88, 116, '\0'   /* zTXt */
        };

        png_set_keep_unknown_chunks(png_ptr, 1 /* PNG_HANDLE_CHUNK_NEVER */,
          chunks_to_ignore, sizeof(chunks_to_ignore)/5);
    }
    #endif`
```

Starting with libpng-1.6.0 it's a lot easier.  You can ignore all
ancillary chunks except for the tRNS chunk by putting "-1"
in the call instead of listing the chunks to be ignored:

```
`
    png_set_keep_unknown_chunks(png,PNG_HANDLE_CHUNK_NEVER, -1, NULL, -1);`
```

See "contrib/gregbook/readpng2.c" that is distributed with libpng for
an example of this.

UPDATE: the cHRM chunk is not necessarily inconsistent.  The latest version of ImageMagick is reporting that it is inconsistent, but that appears to be a bug in ImageMagick.  All the same, it's a good idea to use png_set_keep_unknown_chunks() just to avoid unnecessary processing of the ancillary chunks that you won't be using.